# Run-time error '1004' for WorksheetFunction.AverageIf

Tags: vba, excel

My current issue involves using the `AverageIf` function to calculate average times for certain events (flavor Change, Size Change, and Label Changes). I wrote three separate sections of code to calculate each average time for each event. All three sections are identical (same criteria range, and average range) the only difference is the the criteria.

However, when I run the macro I get the following error:

> Run-time error '1004' Unable  to get the AvergeIf property of
>   WorkksheetFunction class

This error only occurs at the Label Change Section of Code.

Some of my troubleshooting:

- Verify that the string length in the cell is the same as the string in the code
- Verify that the times were in a numerical format
- Checked ranges

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
'Set Criteria Range for Averages
Set crng = Range(Worksheets("DataImport").Cells(StartRowT, "E"), Worksheets("DataImport").Cells(LastRowT, "E"))
'Set Average time ranfe for Averages
Set trng = Range(Worksheets("DataImport").Cells(StartRowT, "G"), Worksheets("DataImport").Cells(LastRowT, "G"))

'Flavor Change
If I > 0 Then
    FlavorA = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(crng, "Flavor Change", trng)
Else
    FlavorA = 0
End If
'Size Change
If M > 0 Then
    SizeChangeA = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(crng, "Size Change", trng)
Else
    SizeChangeA = 0
End If
'Label Change
If J > 0 Then
    LabelA = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(crng, "Label Change", trng)
Else
    LabelA = 0
End If
```

- The letter variables are count variables for the total number of events
- crng is the the criteria range
- trng is the time range (average range)

I am still trying to figure out the exact cause of the run-time error 1004 for the label change section of the code.

Comment: Using the same ranges and criteria, what are the results if you enter the AVERAGEIF formula on the worksheet?  If the criteria do not match (and you get #DIV/0) then this would trigger a run-time error in your VBA.  Instead you can use the `Application.AverageIf()` version which will not throw a run-time error, and test the return value using `IsError()`

Comment: Do you have any cells in `crng` that have the exact text of "Label Change" ? If not then this is the reason you are getting an error, you are trying to calculate an average with zero cells (divide be zero, etc...)

Comment: If no cells meet the "Label Change" criteria, you will get an error, which should equate to #DIV/0 using the worksheet formula.  Best to test for non-zero values before using AVERAGEIF by an IF statement or IIF.

Comment: I get an actual value when I use the averageif formula on the function. There is a cell in crng with the exact text "Label Change"

Answer (score 3):

If the criteria do not match (and you get #DIV/0) then this would trigger a run-time error in your VBA. Instead you can use the `Application.AverageIf()` version (i.e. drop the `WorksheetFunction`) which will not throw a run-time error, and then test the return value using `IsError()`

```
Dim m

'Label Change
If J > 0 Then
    m = Application.AverageIf(crng, "Label Change", trng)
    LabelA = IIf(IsError(m),"value when no match", m)
Else
    LabelA = 0
End If
```

Comment: Tim i do have a criteria that matches in crng. When I run the averageif formula on the data sheet I get the correct value. I added the If then statement to protect the the $DIV/0 error. The J is the number of label changes that occurred. My logic  was if  there were zero label changes then the I would just set the average label change valve to zero.

Comment: So what answer do you get if you enter the corresponding AVERAGEIF formula on the worksheet?

Comment: I get the value 14.9, which is the correct average. There is only one value for the label change.

Comment: Can you share the actual data?

Comment: Yeah I'll Share the worksheet. The issue is in module 3

Comment: When it crashes, the ranges `crng` and `trng` are E50:E51 and G50:G51, but your data only goes to row 50.  You need to reset the value of `StartRowT` (which coming out of your For/Next loop has a value of 51...)

Comment: Thanks Tim I'll give it a try. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just made the change! You are the man! How did you find that error so I don't run into the same problem in the future.

Comment: I hit "Debug" when the error popped up, then typed `? crng.Address` in the Immediate pane in the VB editor and hit enter...  That gave me the range to compare with your input data

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused since you don't have any values in your `crng` range with the value of "Label Change", so you are actually trying to divide by zero - `#DIV/0`.

You can add a criteria to test before calculating the Average of the range, use the code below (per each Average calculation)

```
' at least once cell in the range has the value of "Label Change"
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(crng, "Label Change") > 0 Then
    LabelA = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(crng, "Label Change", trng)
Else
    ' pop a message-box, or whatever you want
    MsgBox "'Label Change' value is not found in range " & crng.Address
End If
```